# How to get value of other ref in schema within Joi.errors()?

Tags: node.js, express, joi

In a Joi schema, I would like to have access to the value of another reference from this schema to print in `Joi.errors()` function ?

I tried to log `.error(() => Joi.ref('name'))` but it gives me 'ref:name'

In the example below, if quantity validation fails, the output will be "Article quantity for 'ref:name' is required." What i want is to output the actual value of `article.name`.

```
const article = Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string()
    .max(128)
    .required(),
  quantity: Joi.number()
    .integer()
    .positive()
    .required()
    .error(() => `Article quantity for '${Joi.ref('name')}' is required.`),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Joi` doesn't support this and you can extract the value yourself.

```
function validateInput(input) {
  const article = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string()
      .max(128)
      .required(),
    quantity: Joi.number()
      .integer()
      .positive()
      .required()
      .error(() => `Article quantity for '${input.name}' is required.`),
  });

  return article.validate(input);
}
```

Please keep in mind, though, that if the [abortEarly](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidatevalue-options) option is set to `false` and `input.name` is not set, error message will become a bit ugly:

```
validateInput({}); // "quantity" fails because [Article quantity for 'undefined' is required.]
```